# What's the difference between "Tokens per Minute Rate Limit (thousands)" and "Rate limit (Tokens per minute)" in Azure OpenAI?

Tags: gpt, openai, api, azure

I deployed GPT-4V on Azure OpenAI. I see:

- Tokens per Minute Rate Limit (thousands): 10
- Rate limit (Tokens per minute): 30000

What's the difference between "Tokens per Minute Rate Limit (thousands)" and "Rate limit (Tokens per minute)" in Azure OpenAI?

---

[image]